# Outdated downvotes problem

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

In my opinion, the current downvote system has two big problems. I need only approving this idea or reporting any problems in answers. If reporting, please explain, why this is a problem.
The first one is with [question #135](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). The reminder isn't shown to users with  ***reputation above 2000***, but they also can downvote, when they can describe, how to improve this question.
The second one is about [the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). It is about the outdated downvotes<sup>1</sup>. The solution is notifications about any edit of downvoted question, as example:

> The downvoted question ["Encouraging people to explain downvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) is edited. Your downvote maybe outdated. Please overview this edit of this question, or your downvote will be deleted after 1 week.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is any downvote, outdated after edit of downvoted question.

Comment: We recommend that new users get a bit familiar with the way our site works *before* suggesting changes, see: [How do I participate on meta and not die trying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying).

Comment: @DonaldDuck that's a good guess, but it's totally unclear what OP is trying to request here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"overview this edit"*? Can you elaborate here in comments?

Comment: I'm pretty sure non of my downvotes get outdated, no matter how much editing is done.

Answer (score 13):

This is a really bad idea, since the system can not check if the edit that was made addressed the reason the post was downvoted in the first place, so it shouldn't be automatically dismissing downvotes.

It also does not address the already cast upvotes, while an edit may certainly make a post worse.

And for posts on meta sites specifically, [voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and an edit isn't suddenly going to make someone agree or disagree with a post.

Once users have around 2000 reputation points, it's reasonable to assume they've downvoted and encountered the reminder before, there's no need to keep reminding them on every single vote they cast.